# What web development tools will allow a page to be viewed by any internet connected device?

Tags: programming-languages, interactive, user-interaction

I know that Apple products like the iPad or the iPhone have trouble with flash apps.

What web development tools should I use in order to avoid compatibility issues when creating a website?  My only constraint is that the languages must provide for interactivity and animation - such as in jQuery.

HTML, CSS, and PHP are a few that I can think of that will behave on 99% of all internet enabled devices.

What tools & languages are available to use when creating a website intended to be viewed on any device's internet "explorer"?

Should I just stick to HTML, CSS, & PHP?  I want a certain level of interactivity so that, for example, a user can hover over images and have pop-ups containing data to appear... or when an object is clicked, an action can happen without a page reload.

Can someone point me in the right direction and help me develop a list of languages that are all-device friendly?

I am familiar with programming in several web-focused languages, I'm just wondering which ones to stay away from.  Certain ones will limit the devices that can view the site and besides that constraint, the site needs to be interactive and animated.

Answer (score 1):

HTML, CSS, PHP, JQUERY are truly your best bet for developing for a wide range of devices.  If the scope of devices is the main goal I would stay away from using HTML5 and CSS3.  You still may run into problems using much jquery with IE7 below.  Mobile browsers on the other hand are much more advanced or up to date with standards then desktop browsers.  I would suggest creating two versions of your application.  One dedicated to running on mobile devices and one for desktop browsers.  It is a shame apple wouldn't support flash applications.  If all you need is hoovers for interaction you won't even need jquery / but for the other it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The "Web" is a name for the concept of having interlinked documents accessible over the internet. Therefore, to have a website you really only need a document able to link to other documents, namely HTML.

HTML is not really a programming language or a tool though, it is a document format.
If you want to make a website you need use HTML to **Markup** what you're writing. Then you use CSS to format different sections of the document you marked up.

PHP though, is completely separate from this, PHP is for creating dynamic HTML, or any document on the server side.

If you want to achieve a flash-effect on a site you use Javascript to modify the page content (HTML) and appearance (CSS).

If you need to learn HTML/CSS I would highly recommend http://htmldog.com/

As per the question, HTML CSS and Javascript are pretty much the only mobile-browser compatible method for website content as they don't need plugins.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make a customized timeline type website in terms of visual appearance and interactivity, but I don't want the info to be limited due to a devices lack of software to view the site